# How to sort alphabetically drop-down list

Tags: javascript, c#

I am creating my own website in **C#**, and I am trying to sort the list of names of some people that I get from the database in alphabetical order (A - Z).

I leave a [jsflidde](https://jsfiddle.net/fpuvh8en/) with an example of what I have done and the function made in **javacript** with which I load the list of people in the drop-down list

```js
function loadResponsable() {
    const url = document.getElementById("responsables").value;
    document.getElementById("AssignDiv").style.display = "block";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            const responsables = document.getElementById("ticketRespInput");

            for (let idx in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(idx)) {
                    const option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.innerHTML = data[idx];
                    option.value = idx;
                    responsables.options.add(option);
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-group" name="asignar" id="AssignDiv">
                                    <label class="required-field" name="asignar" id="lblAssignDiv" for="ticketRespInput">Asignado a:</label>
                                    <select onchange="validate(this)" id="ticketRespInput" name="assigned" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem; height: 50px;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Sin asignar</option>
                                    </select>                                  
                                </div>
```

**UPDATE:**

I add server side code

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult LoadResponsables()
        {
            var groups = new List<string>();

            if (string.Equals(Session["tipo"].ToString(), "super") ||
                string.Equals(Session["tipo"].ToString(), "admin"))
                groups.AddRange(LdapGroupModel.GetAllLdapGoups().LdapGroupsList
                    .Select(ldapGroup => ldapGroup.LdapGroupsId));
            else
                groups.AddRange(LdapGroupModel.GetLdapGroupsFromArea(Session["area"].ToString()).LdapGroupFromArea
                    .Select(ldapGroup => ldapGroup.LdapGroupsId));

            return Json(LdapController.GetUsersByGroup(groups));
        }
```

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: Why don't you get the database to do the sorting? Seems like that would be the easiest solution.

Comment: I can add some default option to fill the drop-down menu if I wish

Comment: OK, but you can do that in the Javascript after you get the data from the database.

Comment: @SebastianSalazar, Howcheng is correct. The place to do the ordering is either  in the database (best) or in the server-side code (second best)

Comment: Check question, I add server side code

Comment: @SebastianSalazar what is the return type of `LdapController.GetUsersByGroup(groups)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this. One option is to use [Sort()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort) on the server-side.  Instead of

```
return Json(LdapController.GetUsersByGroup(groups));
```

You could do:

```
return Json(LdapController.GetUsersByGroup(groups.Sort()));
```

But personally, I would dig into `LdapGroupModel.GetAllLdapGoups()` and find the root query that generates your list, and do the sorting there. I like to sort the data as close to the data source as possible. But that's just me. Either should work!

**EDIT:**

Ok, my mistake.  Try this instead:

```
groups.Sort();
return Json(LdapController.GetUsersByGroup(groups));
```

Comment: Check the question try with your possible solution but it generates the image error

Comment: When I put the `Sort` method in `groups.Sort()`, I get that error message

Comment: Ah! I didn't see that you added a screenshot to your OP. Looking now.

Comment: Even without working, it does not load anything in the drop-down list

Answer (score 1):

You can sort in ascending or descending order when you are fetching from database with SQL or no-SQL syntax and with javascript, you can sor the array 'data' with sort() function.

```
data.sort()
```

put this line before the for loop.

Comment: Testing your possible solution presents me with the following error `Uncaught TypeError: data.sort is not a function`

Comment: try `data.sort` instead of `data.sort()`

Comment: The same mistake, `Uncaught TypeError: data.sort is not a function`

Comment: look at the documentation provided by [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)